# Server-side getting dom properties (height of element)

Tags: html, dom, properties, server-side

I want to scale all the HTML element's height in an HTML page. I am doing this with jQuery height() function, but it takes some time and causes problems in the browser. I decided I want to do this at the server. I tried to do this with ajax. But I couldn't. When I write `height()` function it doesn't return to me value of `height()`. It returns me just `height()` code.

For example:

I will send my html code to server with this function

```
sendHtml('<table><tr><td>'.$variable.'</td></td></table>');
```

Then i get this table's height from server.

Is there another way to do this?

Comment: If you want to do this server-side, you will need to use server-side code. PHP is a common server-side language.

Comment: Are you attempting to change the height based on data recieved from the client (e.g. viewport size)? If that's the case then forget doing it via the server-side. Otherwise could you not just hardcode the height you require?

Comment: i just want to get a table's height via the server-side. Is it possible?

Comment: @CoffeeRain Of course i know php and im using it. This is not a simple question.

Comment: I think maybe there is a server-side tool to run javascript to an html string.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to look into [Node.js](http://nodejs.org/) It's server-side javascript.

Comment: i've looked into it before. I didnt find such a feature in Node.js :(

Comment: Are you talking about a fixed table height? Or a populated table that could vary in height?

Comment: it is not fixed table. It could vary.