# How can I get the computed image width after browser rendering via PHP?

Tags: php, javascript, rhino

I have a server side script that gets the HTML contents of a URL. I need it to get the computed width of elements (specifically images) as the browser would render if with all the CSS attributes applied to it. Something that will do what qQuery's .width method does but in PHP.

Are there any libraries out there capable of doing this? I've heard of Rhino but I am not sure if it has this specific capability.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9732114/convert-html-to-image-in-php

Comment: That is a really tough task. Even with node.js I see there is no solution for this yet (http://stackoverflow.com/a/9121925/779320). I think you should find a work-around to achieve your goal.

Comment: Thanks @ihsan. I decided to go with a workaround. I'm trying to get the most relevant image from any given URL (usually news articles). I decided to use the Boilerpipe API to strip out only the article and find images within that.

Answer (score 0):

The moment something is rendered you have absolute no control of it on PHP, it simples does not know how it was set on the page. What you would have to do is calculate it in javascript and send back that data to PHP through an ajax call.

Comment: He's using a script to get the contents of a URL. It doesn't matter how the contents were set.